# LINQ Query to Return multiple results

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2000

I am trying to write a textbox that will search on 5 DB columns and will return every result of a given search, ex.  "Red" would return:  red ball, Red Williams, etc.  Any examples or similar things people have tried.  My example code for the search.

Thanks.

```
    ItemMasterDataContext db = new ItemMasterDataContext();

    string s = txtSearch.Text.Trim();
    var q = from p in db.ITMSTs
            where p.IMITD1.Contains(s) ||
             p.IMITD2.Contains(s) ||
             p.IMMFNO.Contains(s) ||
             p.IMITNO.Contains(s) ||
             p.IMVNNO.Contains(s)
            select p;

    lv.DataSource = q;
    lv.DataBind();
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? What's wrong with your code? You haven't actually said what your question is. ;)

Comment: to second jalf: what problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this (syntax may be off )

```
using(var db = new ItemMasterDataContext())
{
    var s = txtSearch.Text.Trim();
    var result = from p in db.ITMSTs select p;

    if( result.Any(p=>p.IMITD1.Contains(s))
         lv.DataSource = result.Where(p=>p.IMITD1.Contains(s))
    else if ( result.Any(p=>p.IMITD2.Contains(s))
        lv.DataSource = result.Where(p=>p.IMITD1.Contains(s))

    lv.DataBind();
}
```

or you might want to use this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345073.aspx) or this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.orelse.aspx) from MSDN.

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

"q" in your example will be an `IQueryable<ITMST>`.  I don't think the Datasource property of WebControl know what to do with that.  try writing that line as:

```
 lv.DataSource = q.ToList();
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, web-binding is happy with IEnumerable<T>, which includes IQueryable<T> - so it should be happy. Winform binding would need the ToList(), though.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is generally what people would do using linq. If you wanted to get more complex and use database wild cards then take a look at the SqlMethods class in System.Data.Linq.

@ James Curran
You can assign the DataSource property q and it will work fine. The only different is when the query gets executed.